# Modify a json file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I want to modify my json file without losing the the other string and value

```
const fs = require('fs');
var logPath = 'log.json'
var logRead = fs.readFileSync(logPath)
var logFile = JSON.parse(logRead)



LogChannel = '2'
Server = 'Number2'
User = 300


if (!logFile[Server]){
    
    logFile[Server] = {'LogChannelId': LogChannel ,'NumberOfUser':User }
    fs.writeFileSync(logPath, JSON.stringify(logFile, null, 2));
  }
else {

    logFile[Server] = {'NumberOfUser':User+1}
    fs.writeFileSync(logPath, JSON.stringify(logFile, null, 2));

}
```

When json object is created I have the two String with the value

```
{
  "Number1": {
    "LogChannelId": "2",
    "NumberOfUser": 300
  },
  "Number2": {
    "LogChannelId": "2",
    "NumberOfUser": 300
  }
}
```

After modify my json file I lost LogChannelId string

```
{
  "Number1": {
    "LogChannelId": "2",
    "NumberOfUser": 300
  },
  "Number2": {
    "NumberOfUser": 301
  }
}
```

How can I keep my LogChannelId string and be able to modify only NumberOfUser

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Max. Don't forget to upvote helpful answers and accept answers that solve your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of overriding the entire object you can just assign a new value to one of its keys.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
var logPath = 'log.json'
var logRead = fs.readFileSync(logPath)
var logFile = JSON.parse(logRead)

var LogChannel = '2'
var Server = 'Number2'
var User = 300


if (!logFile[Server]){
    logFile[Server] = {'LogChannelId': LogChannel ,'NumberOfUser':User }
    fs.writeFileSync(logPath, JSON.stringify(logFile, null, 2));
  }
else {
    logFile[Server].NumberOfUser = User+1;
// CHANGE --------------^
    fs.writeFileSync(logPath, JSON.stringify(logFile, null, 2));
}
```

Comment: Thank your awnser was very helpful

Comment: No worries. Feel free to mark this as the answer if it helped.